# Theme does not allow JavaScript to be executed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm running WordPress 4.2.2 with the theme Curio: http://themeforest.net/item/curio-clean-creative-website-template/503953

On this template I'm allowed to have JavaScript directly typed into my code editor on regular pages.
However, when I switch to another theme - any standard WordPress theme - the JavaScript is not executed and every line in the code is appended with

...

.

Can I somehow allow the JavaScript to be accepted on the standard WordPress themes as well?

I know this is not "good" behaviour but I need to switch theme and cannot create plugins or other for the JavaScript code.

Comment: Why don't you just add the necessary js code in the custom.js file of the theme?

Comment: Is the site live to have a quick look at?

Comment: I only want specific code on specific pages

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not allow any JavaScript in the body of it's posts or pages. It is for a good reason - security. It is best to add your custom JS functionality to your theme or its [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in case you don't want (can't) modify your main theme.

If you need JavaScript in posts to embed some off-site content, like YouTube videos, WP supports oEmbed. For more information on oEmbed and a list of available content providers, check out [this page](http://oembed.com/).

Having said that, if you absolutely need to have the ability to add custom JavaScript code to your posts, it's still possible using custom code or dedicated plugins.

Below are a couple of plugins that do that: (in a number of ways for you to choose from)

- [Code Embed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-embed-code/)
- [Insert Html Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/)